# Store values are undefined on react using mobx

Tags: reactjs, store, ecmascript-5, mobx, mobx-react

I have very simple configuration on mobx/react . I was trying to make simple store for notes like below

```
//modal class
class Note {
    @observable body;
    @observable date;
    @observable by;
    @observable starred;

    constructor(body, by) {
        this.body = body;
        this.date = date.now();
      this.by=by;
      this.starred=false;
    }
}


//controller class
class NoteList {
    @observable notes = [];
    @computed get StarredNote() {
        return this.notes.filter(note => note.starred).length;
    }
}


const note_store =  new NoteList();
export default note_store
console.log('here');
console.log(note_store);


note_store.notes.push(
    new Note("Note 1",'SB'),
    new Note("Note 2",'PS')
);
```

but I got note_store value undefined , what is wrong here?

My .babelrc

```
{
  "presets" : ["es2015", "react"],
  "plugins": ["transform-class-properties","transform-decorators-legacy"]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I nailed it , it was due to order of plugin

**From documentation**

**NOTE: Order of Plugins Matters!**

If you are including your plugins manually and using transform-class-properties, make sure that transform-decorators-legacy comes before transform-class-properties.

```
/// WRONG

"plugins": [
  "transform-class-properties",
  "transform-decorators-legacy"
]

// RIGHT

"plugins": [
  "transform-decorators-legacy",
  "transform-class-properties"
]
```

more https://github.com/loganfsmyth/babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy